# Como paso una variable php a javascript y viseversa

Tags: javascript, php

Creo que la pregunta es demasiado simple, ¿Como paso una variable php a javascript y viseversa?
tengo el siguiente script aun que me parece que es correcto no lo se bien tengo mas de 5 años que no hagoe esto asi que se me olvido.

```
    <?php
    $valor_bcv = "24.05";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           var ves,resultado; 
           ves = "<?php echo $valor_bcv; ?>";
           resultado ='3,0';
           "<?php echo $val; ?>" = resultado;
    </script>
<?php echo "el numero es: ".$val; ?>
```

Comment: De esa forma yo paso las variables de php a javascript haciendo un `echo $variable`, tal cual como lo muestras en el codigo que insertaste.

Comment: Considera usar Ajax, o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Ya no se hacen las cosas mezclando código PHP en Javascript, eso era en la prehistoria. Ajax o Fetch permiten enviar y traer cosas entre cliente / servidor de una forma limpia, segura y transparente, sin necesidad de recargar la página a cada iteracción del usuario.

Comment: Esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/584803/20709 muestra varias alternativas

Comment: Lo mejor es NO HACERLO, si tienes que hacer algo asi ya partimos de una terrible base, hay que mirar otras formas, por algo el backend es backend y el frontend es frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como te lo dice @A.Cedano, ya no es optimo hacer eso, puedes hacerlo con JSON también, pero respondiendo exactamente a tu pregunta, el código seria:

```
<?php
    $valor_bcv = "24.05";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let ves,resultado;
    ves = "<?php echo $valor_bcv; ?>";
    alert(ves);
    resultado = "3.0";
    <?php $val = "<script> document.writeln(resultado); </script>";?>
</script>
<?php
    echo "El numero es: ".$val;
    
    // El numero es: 3.0
?>
```